# Google Chrome API: How do I add my app to show an icon on the "New Tab" (Apps) page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed that a "New Tab" page has an apps section, but by default an application is not added there. What do I need to do to have my application appear there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hosted apps and packed apps](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/choosing.html) will automatically add an icon to the new tab page. Make sure you have a good 128 pixel [icon](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/images.html#icons) registered in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html

Add to manifest:

```
"app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  },
```

You'll also need a 128x128 icon, specify it here:

```
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your chrome is set to open multiple pages, do the following:

1. go to "Settings"
2. Go to the second sub-heading "On startup"
3. Make sure the 3rd choice is selected "Open a specific...or set of pages"
4. Click on "Set Page"
5. On Add New Page type "www.google.com"
6. Press "Enter"
7. Highlight the hyperlink "www.google.com" press delete

You should see a blank line where the apps tab should be, but it's not empty.